# Make a html or xhtml page with svg displayed in local

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg, xhtml, localhost

I have a `html` page which have a svg. I use `Chrome 54.0.2840.98 (64-bit)` as web browser in Mac OS.

The svg is displayed well with localhost, whereas it is not displayed when i specify `file:///Users/softtimur/...` in the browser path.

I have searched some threads, some suggested to change the page to `xhtml`, I did it. And make the header as follows:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
```

But the svg is still not shown in local.

Could anyone help?

PS: [Here](http://pastebin.com/841LhCdy) is the file. After downloading it, you may need to change the name `test.xhtml.txt` to `test.xhtml`.

Edit: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240867/error-on-chrome-when-trying-to-access-svg-in-object) mentions that `Chrome may block the access to local documents (Object in your case) from remote scripts (svg-pan-zoom)`. Is there a way that I rewrite the page to find a workaround? Or could I do something about Chrome settings? I really don't want to use `localhost`.

Comment: Please show the entire file. Is it a XHTML file containing an <svg> element ?

Comment: I just uploaded a file, please see OP.

Comment: The uploaded file works fine if I have a D3 script available locally. i.e. have d3 file on the same folder and use `<script src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>`. I also don't see that it loads any external resources that could cause a cross origin issue. I can see the svg object containing 3 dots with two arrows. If this isn't case, are there any errors from console log?

Comment: Indeed... actually, `http://` should be added if we want to use the external `d3`. So by using `<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>`, a html file without `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />` works already... Thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Chainat and I discovered (in comments), the key is to write `<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>` (over `<script src="d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>`) if one wants to use external d3. Then even a html file without `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />` works...

Answer (score -1):

First of all.
SVG's Doctype will not start with html.
svg doctype is

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
```

Here is the link for "Doctype's" [https://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html][1].

Could you conduct another test, like opening SVG file from folder, if windows then windows explorer, by double clicking the file. It should open in your default web browser.

I have not seen this when I open my files "file:///", instead I see Drive "C:/" like this.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I use Mac OS... Double clicking the file in `Finder` does open the link in my default web browser (i.e., Chrome), and the svg is not shown.